# Selecting multiple rows based on different column values

Tags: python, pandas, isin

I'm trying to evaluate some images based on the classification. I use the piece of code below to read the csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)
```

So I have something that looks like this:

```
Image1  2  3  4  5  Green
Image1  3  4  5  6  Red
Image2  4  5  6  7  Red
Image3  1  4  8  9  Green
Image4  5  3  0  1  Yellow
Image4  6  2  1  1  Green
```

So in case I want to keep the images with the value "Green" the output should look like this:

```
Image1  2  3  4  5  Green
Image1  3  4  5  6  Red
Image3  1  4  8  9  Green
Image4  5  3  0  1  Yellow
Image4  6  2  1  1  Green
```

which means that I want to keep the images with the same id in the first column when there is at least one with the element I check is in the last column.

I used the `isin` method but I don't know how to keep the images the rest of the rows with the images that do have at least on time the value "Green" in the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `GroupBy.any` here, where we check if any of the rows suffice our condition:

```
df[df[5].eq("Green").groupby(df[0]).transform("any")]

        0  1  2  3  4       5
0  Image1  2  3  4  5   Green
1  Image1  3  4  5  6     Red
3  Image3  1  4  8  9   Green
4  Image4  5  3  0  1  Yellow
5  Image4  6  2  1  1   Green
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked for one class. Is there any way that I can include two conditions? Like "Green" and "Red"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc` to find the values in the first column where the 6th column is `Green`, and use that as your values to pass to `isin`:

```
df[df[0].isin(df.loc[df[5] == "Green", 0])]
# if it has to be the last column, instead of the 6h column, use `iloc` instead:
# df[df[0].isin(df.loc[df.iloc[:, -1] == "Green", 0])]

Image1  2  3  4  5  Green
Image1  3  4  5  6  Red
Image3  1  4  8  9  Green
Image4  5  3  0  1  Yellow
Image4  6  2  1  1  Green
```

**Breaking it down**:

the inner `loc` retrieves the Images that contain `Green` in the first column:

```
df.loc[df[5] == "Green", 0] 
0    Image1
3    Image3
5    Image4
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Passing that to `isin`, you get a boolean mask of where the first column matches one of those values:

```
df[0].isin(df.loc[df[5] == "Green", 0])
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Which you can use to filter your `df`:

```
df[df[0].isin(df.loc[df[5] == "Green", 0])]
```